# Rotate files in filesystem when full or send to /dev/null

Tags: linux, filesystems, fuse

I'm looking for a solution to this problem:

A remote job (CI job) is creating a lot of DEBUG files (logs) I would like to keep, but after some time the disk space is totally filled up before the end of the job and I can't get the resulting files because the job fails. My use case is that ccache is in debug mode and writes all debug files to a folder, and during compilation that folder continues to fill-up until the disk is full and compilation is not finished, leading to a failing job on "no more free disk space"

I thought maybe I could use fuse filesystem stored in a file of the device. That file/filesystem would have a fixed size, eg. 500MB.

When the filesystem is full I would like it to fail silently and don't have an error "no more disk space". The filesystem could either free space by deleting the older files or just fail silently and send everything coming once the filesystem is full to /dev/null

Is this possible? Does there exist a (fuse) filesystem with such a feature or do you have another solution?

This is on linux Debian.

Thanks

Comment: What if you create a partition for your log that is 500MB and write to it there? If the log is full, the log cannot be appended anymore, but the job may still work regardless.

Comment: Not sure that it will work because it is ccache which reported that disk is full and then stopped the process. I will give it a try. (I guess I can't create a partition in a docker, but probably it's ok to mount a filesystem in a file)

Comment: Are you able to change the logging to syslog or a pipe?

Comment: @davidgo : ccache doesn't permit this

Comment: @LPChip result is: it doesn't work, ccache fails by telling the disk that holds the debug folder is full; the CI job then fails on this.

Comment: It may be that you need to write your own FUSE filesystem. While this is not trivial, using a framework like fusepy should allow you to create something in under 100 lines if code.

Comment: For now, I found [limit-fs](https://github.com/piuma/limit-fs) and  [rotatefs](https://github.com/frt/rotatefs). They remove old files. I didn't find any which keeps the old files and doesn't write the new ones if disk is full.